# Testbox 2.1 - Skip an entire directory or CFC file

Tags: coldfusion, testbox

We want to create a `HelperUtility.cfc` with common methods for our tests to use. If we put the file in `/tests/lib/HelperUtility.cfc`, can we tell TestBox, don't try running any tests in /tests/lib? If not, can we add something to the component tag to skip the entire file, rather than adding `skip` to all the methods in the component individually?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that unfortunately.
I have tried to skip some manual mocks that were created inside a `tests/mock` folder, but you cannot configure `TestBox` at runtime to skip a specific folder if you decide to run the tests for a parent folder.

The only work around that worked for me was to create a `specs` subfolder in the parent `tests` and then call the `testbox` runner with a directory argument of the specs...
For example: `http://localhost:8500/testbox/system/runners/HTMLRunner.cfm?directory=tests.specs`